# Run a function in parent iframe when child is on certain page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, parent-child

I have no access to the child frame content.

I would like to run a function on the parent when the child iframe goes to a certain page.

The child's URL does not change, only the content on the page.

Is it possible to run the function on the parent frame based from content shown on the child frame?

The child frame content does have a unique id="" tag that the parent frame could look for so could this be used?

Comment: @frobinsonj I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked, because the OP stated that the src of the `<iframe>` doesn't change.

Comment: Removed. My bad, thanks @David

Comment: Correct, I am looking to run the function on the parent frame when an id="" tag inside the child frame appears on screen. As this has a unique identifier linked to a div on the last page, this is when I want the button to appear on the parent frame. But thank you @frobinsonj

Comment: Is the iframe source the same origin as the page?

Comment: It isn't no, its an external webpage. 

My thought is:
The user is required to click through the child's webpage 
Step 1, step 2, step 3 (same URL but different page)

Once the user has read the step 3 page in the child frame, the parent frame shows a button to 'continue'

The function to show the 'continue' button could be based off a html ID tag as its unique to that section (step 3) @frobinsonj

Comment: Looking into some documentation and examples

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

They are able to change the html and css based in the child frame so surely I can check for a unique ID tag?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done due to cross origin issues. Understandable security flaw!

Solution is it's the same domain is getChildElementById('')..

Or if you have access to the child domain to out an eventListener in place.

We do have access to the child frame but not enough functionality to add this in